# How do I add an iOS app filter to an image in HTML?

Tags: html, ios, icons, masking

I want to turn a regular icon (like this: http://a1075.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/db/4a/c3/db4ac3d6-64ef-1bea-9c2e-f48e5b29022b/mzl.itlrenhu.png )
into one with iOS app borders in HTML (like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/35/Geometry_Dash_Logo.PNG )
but I can't find out how websites like iTunes make these images into app icons without using transparency.
Any help? :/

Comment: And why do you think transparency isn't involved?

Comment: It isn't ALWAYS involved. In sites like iTunes, the app icon appears to have app borders, but going into the site's html shows that the real file is a full icon, like the first link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (css):

```
border-radius: 8px;
```

Comment: Well, it should be something like `border-radius: 200px;` for this large image you provided in your question.